# How to install custom modules in OpenERP 7 on Windows?

Tags: windows, openerp-7

Title says it all: I know nothing about OpenERP and need to help someone use a custom module on which it's built.

The computer is running Windows. After running the OpenERP 7 Windows installer, it now has OpenERP and PostgreSQL installed, but I don't know how to proceed to install the custom module:

1. Where is the "addon" directory on Windows?
2. Will installing the custom module automatically install dependencies, including standard OpenERP modules on which it depends?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps:

1. Copy your module into C:\Program Files (x86)\openerp v7\server\openerp\addons
2. Lunch openerp by : localhost:8069
3. In openerp click Settings/Updates Modules List (if setting don't appear click users. then choose administrator and select Technical Features)
4. Then click on modules, and search your module in the search field.
5. Click install.

You should now see your module in the top of the page if it have a menu.